# Is there a way to calculate a SUM of a Count Alias in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a custom SQL report that will give me a percentage of DispositionCodes that are clicked after a customer service rep ends a call with a customer.

I am currently using a COUNT Alias to count how many times a Disposition code is assigned to a customer call. I would then like to summarize that *DispositionCount* alias into another column called "Total". Then I would like to see the percentage of times that a disposition code is selected by calculating `DispositionCount / Total`. Is it possible to SUM an alias to give me a Total count, and then calculate a percentage based off of two Alias columns?

CURRENT QUERY:

```
SELECT
    WrapupData,
    ISNULL(WrapupData, 'No Dispos Code Entered') as DispositionCode,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN WrapupData IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS DispositionCount
FROM Termination_Call_Detail tcd
LEFT JOIN dbo.t_Call_Type ct ON ct.CallTypeID = tcd.CallTypeID
GROUP BY
    WrapupData
```

CURRENT OUTPUT

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|                     |                         |                     |                  
+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
| WrapupData          | DispositionCode         |  DispositionCount   |
| NULL                | No Dispos Code Entered  |  8                  |
| Appointment Request | Appointment Request     |  3                  |
+---------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------+
| WrapupData          | DispositionCode         | DispositionCount |Total | Percentage|
| NULL                | No Dispos Code Entered  | 8                | 11   | 72.72     |
| Appointment Request | Appointment Request     | 3                | 11   | 27.27     |
+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

I have tried `count(sum(WrapupData))`
but WrapupData is varchar and invalid for sum operator.

I have also tried `count(sum(DispositionCount))`
but DispositionCount comes back as an Invalid column name (I'm assuming because it's an Alias and is only temporary)

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated tags: SSMS has nothing to with the problem at hand and MySql and MS SQL Server are completely different products.

Comment: @Filburt The SQL Server tag itself was most likely appropriate here.

Comment: @Filburt noted. Thank you I am somewhat new to SQL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use analytic functions here:

```sql
SELECT
    WrapupData,
    ISNULL(WrapupData, 'No Dispos Code Entered') AS DispositionCode,
    COUNT(WrapupData) AS DispositionCount,
    SUM(COUNT(WrapupData)) OVER () AS Total,
    100.0 * COUNT(WrapupData) / SUM(COUNT(WrapupDatalse)) OVER () AS Percentage
FROM Termination_Call_Detail tcd 
LEFT JOIN dbo.t_Call_Type ct
    ON ct.CallTypeID = tcd.CallTypeID
GROUP BY
    WrapupData;
```

The here is to use `SUM()` with a window over the entire table, post aggregation, to find the total.  We can also find the percentage by normalizing the count using this sum.

Comment: Thank you. I had to make a few changes due to the database schema, but I got my desired output! It looks like I need to do some research on some Analytic Functions :)

Comment: @DerrikAntrium ... yes, analytic functions are very useful in a few different areas, and they are worth learning.